# Trying to delete a program that's not open, but says it is?

Tags: permission, file

I've recently become nigh on obsessive with cleaning out extra space on my hard drive, and I'm trying to delete a program called "Rowmote Helper." Whenever I try to delete it, it says it can't be deleted because it is open. But when I open the "force quit applications" window, it's not running. What can I do to quit the program if it's running, or force delete it anyway? How do you force-delete an application that says that its running, but when you try to force quit it, it doesn't show up?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to Applications > Utilities and open up Activity Monitor. Scroll down until you find your application. Highlight it and click the "Quit Process" button in the upper left. Now it is no longer running and can be deleted from your computer.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not listed in Activity Monitor, you can probably delete it using Terminal.

Open Applications -> Terminal.

First type:

```
rm -rf
```

*Note there must be a "space" typed after the "-rf". But don't panic if you miss it, because rm will just complain about "illegal option" and you can try again.*

Then drag the file from the Finder window into Terminal, that will make Terminal insert the full path to that file for you.

Press Enter and the file should be deleted.

If it still refuses to delete (not likely), then try restarting the machine before retrying this.

Answer (score -2):

On Microsoft Windows 7 just type %appdata% in the Start Menu and find the program. Delete it from there and it will be gone.

Comment: Might be difficult on OS X though...